# multiple information recorded to SD

Tags: raspbian

I was wondering if it was possible to have my pi running GPS to get real time, height and speed information, also have a camera attached that will be recording and have multiple accelerometers feeding in information. I want to be able to record all the information to the SD card to analyse at a later date.

Comment: yes, it is possible to do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It will be easiest if you use a distribution such as Raspbian which is Linux based.  Linux is a multi-user multi-tasking system which can easily handle your requirements.

Comment: Thank you when using Raspian can I still code so the system runs with out user input. So when power is applied the pi will automatically start recording and gathering data until power is removed

Comment: Yes you can.  However note that the Pi will take of the order of 30 seconds to boot and start running your code, it's not like an Arduino which will start up in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

It really depends on what do you mean by **real-time** and what do you expect.

Recording a compressed image on the SD card every 10 seconds is fine, but encoding a video stream may be out of the CPU performance of the PI.

Recording GPS position and speed will just work, since the update speed will be low (some update per second at max).

And about the accelerometers, it should work, unless you expect to sample them at a very regular interval (since your operating system is not real-time), and not too fast.

Comment: I have used Arduino for GPS and vibration information and plan on using the pi to extract the info from the Arduino and record it to the SD card, also use the pi to record video which will be saved on the card. I am though currently having issues with my pi activating the serial port I have seen various videos and threads on different web sites but still at a stand still.